# SQL Is there a more efficient method than CASE results based upon varying criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

The below case statement does not seem to be the best or most efficient method for the result I am looking for.

The result needs to be on 1 line in 1 field as shown below in the result. If there is 1 PO and 1 IREQ the result should show "1 PO, 1 IREQ" on the line in the LINE_COMMENT field. If there is only 2 PR, the result should show "2 PR" on the line in the LINE_COMMENT field.  This process will repeat about 65K times with varying result.

A line today could change tomorrow when re-queried based upon data changes (e.g. today result could be "1 PO, 2 PR", tomorrow line result could be "2 PO".

Additionally, the PO count comes from its own table while PR and IREQ come from another table with both joined to another table with 2 unique keys.

Being a newer self taught analyst I have only tried a Case statement. Please advise if there is a more efficient way to handle this, especially since the full query will handle ~30 different combinations.

Below is a sample of a larger statement needed to look up data based upon a specific criteria.

```
CASE
    WHEN COUNT PO >= 1 THEN
        CASE
            WHEN COUNT PR >= 1 THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN COUNT IREQ >= 1 THEN
                        PO, PR, IREQ
                    ELSE
                        PO, PR
                END
            WHEN COUNT IREQ >= 1 THEN
                    PO, IREQ
            ELSE
                PO  
            END
    WHEN COUNT PR >= 1 THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN COUNT IREQ >= 1 THEN
                PR, IREQ
            ELSE
                PR
        END
    WHEN COUNT IREQ >= 1 THEN
        IREQ
END LINE_COMMENT
```

```
PO  PR  IREQ    RESULT for LINE_COMMENT
1   3   1       1 PO, 3 PR, 1 IREQ
2   1   0       2 PO, 1 PR
1   0   1       1 PO, 1IREQ
1   0   0       1 PO 
0   2   1       2 PR, 1 IREQ 
0   1   0       1 PR 
0   0   2       2 IREQ 
0   0   0       NO RESULTS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or maybe you want the DECODE:

```
select decode(po, 0, '', TO_CHAR(po) || ' PO, ') 
       || decode(pr, 0, '', TO_CHAR(pR) || ' PR, ') 
       || decode(ireq, 0, '', TO_CHAR(ireq) || ' IREQ ') LINE_COMMENT
from test;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=78117dc215f874f8254528eba953e713)

RESULT:

```
LINE_COMMENT
1 PO, 3 PR, 1 IREQ 
2 PO, 1 PR, 
1 PO, 1 IREQ 
1 PO, 
2 PR, 1 IREQ 
1 PR, 
2 IREQ
```

After the comment from @Littlefoot I have changed it to this:

```
select decode(LINE_COMMENT, '', 'NO RESULTS', rtrim(LINE_COMMENT,','))  LINE_COMMENT
from (
select decode(po, 0, '', TO_CHAR(po) || ' PO,') 
       || decode(pr, 0, '', TO_CHAR(pR) || ' PR,') 
       || decode(ireq, 0, '', TO_CHAR(ireq) || ' IREQ') LINE_COMMENT
from test);
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c1e1fd14bac4d50ce84b1419df36202f)

Result:

```
LINE_COMMENT
1 PO,3 PR,1 IREQ
2 PO,1 PR
1 PO,1 IREQ
1 PO
2 PR,1 IREQ
1 PR
2 IREQ
NO RESULTS
```

Comment: A few trailing commas & missing "NO RESULTS" spoils it.

Comment: It certainly does.

Comment: O, I did not see you are using decode, I sow first `case when` and have seen that the results are great... well both are ok :)

Comment: Nema na čemu, i drugi put.

Answer (score 1):

Not too pretty, but works (kind of).

`placeholder` is here just to visually separate `ireq` from `line_comment`.

Although `CASE` is a preferable option, `decode` is simpler to use in *this case*.

```
SQL> with test (po, pr, ireq) as
  2    (select 1, 3, 1 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 1, 0 from dual union all
  4     select 1, 0, 1 from dual union all
  5     select 1, 0, 0 from dual union all
  6     select 0, 2, 1 from dual union all
  7     select 0, 1, 0 from dual union all
  8     select 0, 0, 2 from dual union all
  9     select 0, 0, 0 from dual
 10    )
 11  select po, pr, ireq, '->  ' placeholder,
 12         case when po = 0 and pr = 0 and ireq = 0 then 'NO RESULTS'
 13              else decode(po  , 0, null, po || ' PO') ||
 14                   decode(pr  , 0, null, decode(po, 0, null, ', ') || pr || ' PR') ||
 15                   decode(ireq, 0, null, decode(pr, 0, decode(po, 0, null, ', '), ', ') || ireq || ' IREQ')
 16         end line_comment
 17  from test;

        PO         PR       IREQ PLAC LINE_COMMENT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ----------------------------------------
         1          3          1 ->   1 PO, 3 PR, 1 IREQ
         2          1          0 ->   2 PO, 1 PR
         1          0          1 ->   1 PO, 1 IREQ
         1          0          0 ->   1 PO
         0          2          1 ->   2 PR, 1 IREQ
         0          1          0 ->   1 PR
         0          0          2 ->   2 IREQ
         0          0          0 ->   NO RESULTS

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```